# How should cancellation tokens be used in IHostedService?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library

The [ASP.NET Core 2.0 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.0) defines the IHostedService interface as follows:

> StartAsync(CancellationToken) - Called after the server has started and IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted is triggered. StartAsync contains the logic to start the background task.
>
> StopAsync(CancellationToken) - Triggered when the host is performing a graceful shutdown. StopAsync contains the logic to end the background task and dispose of any unmanaged resources. If the app shuts down unexpectedly (for example, the app's process fails), StopAsync might not be called.

If `StopAsync` is called to shut down the service, then what are the cancellation token parameters used for? How exactly should they be used?

Comment: Do the interface comments clear it up? https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/ae9da9290eb825f4145aaaa23603186d51211e53/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/IHostedService.cs

Comment: I think so, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cancellation token passed to `IHostedService.StopAsync()` originates from [`WebHost.StopAsync()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/cd3f58bed7234ed5035a995c8688dccd6706b584/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/WebHost.cs#L304) and is usually a cancellation token that is tied to the default shutdown command for an ASP.NET Core application (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or `SIGTERM`). This token is linked with a new token that is tied to a (configurable) time-out. For example, see the [`RunAsync()` extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/a63932a492513cdeb4935661145084cad2ae5521/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostExtensions.cs#L88). I believe the default time-out is 5 seconds. This means that cancellation will be requested when the host calls `Cancel()` on the token source or when the time-out kicks in.

Comment: Hey All , I am kind of confused here especially on StopAsync(CancellationToken token) side. When I look at the docs I see that this token has not been cosumed or used in the StopAsync method so what I am supposed to do with the token in StopAsync method. Any help is appreciated ?

Answer (score 2):

`CancellationToken` on `StopAsync()` indicates that the shutdown process should no longer be graceful.